# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS on RTOS

Tags: ros, embedded

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Does ROS have/or will it have support for any RTOS? e.g QNX, Vxworks, LynxOS...

My requirement is not real-time processing. I am happy with normal ubuntu performance. However there occur situations where an existing project is already on say QNX. How do I compile ROS on such an OS. Any proven success on a specific OS? Any Existing blogs, posts etc. please share.

Cheers
Aswin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52149/ros-on-rtos/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is a very interesting discussion.
ROS at the moment neither is a realtime robotic framework nor has integration with any of these Real Time OS. AFAIK the only you can do is send strategical/non-realtime orders to a real-time system (ie: realtime microcontroller like arduino) and it would be the responsable to acomplish the real time goals. See: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial. Of course the realtime contstraints wouldn't be warranted until the rt-microcontroler has received the commands (since the rosserial communications are not realtime).

There are other robotic software frameworks like looks more prepared to work for real time systems like: YARP or OROCOS.
See this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921889012000322) to know which operative systems they support.

However there are some packages that looks prepared to work for real time systems:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism?distro=groovy
It's not to much well explained how these mechanisms work in real time over a non-real time system like ubuntu-linux (Perhaps they don't run on ubuntu. The PR2 experts should know it)

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6